# Change clustered columns in an existing bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a partitioned and clustered table in bigquery. I would like to add another column to the set of clustered columns. I found out that the way to fix it is creating another table as you can see here [Make existing bigquery table clustered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52077498/make-existing-bigquery-table-clustered), but I can't do it because my table is the source of a Data Studio dashboard where I have many calculated fields and I don't want to lose these fields.

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Gustavo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a new table, although changing cluster column was not supported initially, it is supported afterwards (since early 2020).

Please check this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables#modifying-cluster-spec

Unfortunately, the feature is only available through API right now.

(If you're not familiar with BigQuery API) It doesn't require you to write code, you can interact with [API web interface](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) here. For your one time maintenance, it may save you some time.

Comment: Thanks a lot @YunZhang. It worked like a charm through API web interface.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't think BigQuery yet allows renaming a table.*
Can you use view? So copy data to another table with required modified clustering. Then have a view with same name as the old table name on the new table, so that nothing breaks on Data Studio.